# Filtering the Ansible Output and print it

Tags: json, linux, ansible, filtering

I am trying to filter the ansible below ansible output in JSON to retrieve the value of **Key**. Please fnd the below output.

New KEY value to be extracted.

```
    "msg": {
    "allow": "GET, POST",
    "cache_control": "no-cache, no-store",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content_disposition": "attachment; filename=response",
    "content_language": "en",
    "content_length": "994",
    "content_type": "application/json",
    "cookies": {
        "session_id": "cd67b9ff4a9e35c7949b03ce5afde96de9d7147b"
    },
    "cookies_string": "session_id=cd67b9ff4a9e35c7949b03ce5afde96de9d7147b",
    "date": "Fri, 12 Feb 2021 07:59:55 GMT",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "expires": "0",
    "failed": false,
    "json": {
        "items": [
            {
                "body": {
                    "name": "admin",
                    "password": {
                        "key": "a1c20753-4ce7-4d8b-aef8-611f0ded49c5",
                        "meta": {
                            "href": "/api/configuration/passwords#a1c20753-4ce7-4d8b-aef8-611f0ded49c5"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "key": "12372718655d3883ec89c09",
                "meta": {
                    "href": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/users/12372718655d3883ec89c09"
                }
            }
        ],
        "meta": {
            "first": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/groups",
            "href": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/users",
            "last": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/users",
            "next": null,
            "parent": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database",
            "previous": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/groups",
            "remaining_seconds": 600,
            "transaction": "/api/transaction"
        }
    },
```

The square braces after the items is causing the issue and i am not able to reach until the key. Can you please help me out. I have filter the parameter Key and pass this to a differnt task in the playbook. I tried using the debug as below but it didn't work out.

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ json.items[0].key }}"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You can update your question with  associated ansible code snippets and error logs to provide more insights.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from the question whether you already have the JSON or you get it from some other ansible task.

---

Assuming that we have the JSON ready, you can get the `key` as shown in the below playbook.

> Note: I have updated the key `items` as it conflicts with the ansible
> functions, as I noticed the same while using `items` to get the key
> value.

```
---
- name: extract key from json
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - json: {
        "abc": [
          {
            "body": {
              "name": "admin",
              "password": {
                "key": "26b2fd50-a853-4a8d-a35e-8cfbe98cea5f",
                "meta": {
                  "href": "/api/configuration/passwords#26b2fd50-a853-4a8d-a35e-8cfbe98cea5f"
                }
              }
            },
            "key": "12372718655d3883ec89c09",
            "meta": {
              "href": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/users/12372718655d3883ec89c09"
            }
          }
        ],
        "meta": {
          "first": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/groups",
          "href": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/users",
          "last": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/users",
          "next": null,
          "parent": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database",
          "previous": "/api/configuration/aaa/local_database/groups",
          "remaining_seconds": 600,
          "transaction": "/api/transaction"
        }
      }

  tasks:
    - name: print_json
      debug:
        msg: "{{ json.abc[0].key }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The one i pasted above is the JSOn Output. I am getting it from previous task. I am trying to pass that key value to another task in the playbook. Hope this makes sense..!@Shubham Vaishnav

Also, I want to filter this key value key": "12372718655d3883ec89c09", Not the one you added. ! Sorry for the confusion shubham

Comment: Update my answer to extract the key you mentioned.

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks but this is not working..!

Comment: I have also tried the same way as mentioned in my question but it didn't work out..!

Comment: Add the error trace or something in your question which I can see, otherwise, there is no way to fix the issue.

Comment: Hey Shubham, I have pasted the complete output in the question and error i am getting. Can you please have a look.

Comment: I think you have not read my answer properly, I have mentioned in the `NOTE` that `items` is ansible reseverd function. Hence, when you use `json.items` it fails there. You will have to update it.

Comment: Sorry, i missed it. But i am not able to parse it yet. When you say to update the items ? How should i do that ? is it like i need to have a different var ? Please help me out..!@shubham Vaishnav

Comment: @SyedBasha I want you to change the items key ( this items key in your json  `"json": { "items": [`  ) to any string in the world except for reserved keywords and it will work. Like I changed it to `abc` in my JSON in my answer.

Comment: Hi, this output i am getting from previous task which is being carried out to the next task. Here i am not sure how i can change the value to different one..!